# Unity InputSystem will Send but not Broadcast

Tags: unity, input, messaging

I'm trying to organise my project so that each MonoBehaviour receives relevant impulses/actions and handles them.

I have the following:

`InputManager`: Empty game object with a PlayerInput component. Used to configure/switch mappings, handle input-related functionality.

`MapController`: GameObject with lots of functionality and children that sits alongside the InputManager. Needs to be aware when the `ToggleView` action is fired.

I have an appropriate action (tied to the spacebar):

[image: Action for "ToggleView" bound to Keyboard/SpaceBar]

The PlayerInput is set to Broadcast:

[image]

If I create a `public void OnToggleView() { ... }` in `MapController`, it never fires.

However, if I attach the following to the same GameObject as the PlayerInput...

```
public class TestShim : MonoBehaviour {
    public void OnToggleView() {
        Debug.Log("Test shim toggled");
    }
}
```

It fires just fine.

Same if I switch the mode from Broadcast to Send.

I was under the impression that Broadcasting should check for relevant methods on all enabled GameObjects?

What am I missing / how can I raise the event in `MapController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/manual/Components.html#notification-behaviors

Broadcast messages uses [GameObject.BroadcastMessage](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.BroadcastMessage.html) which sends the message to the gameobject and any of its children, not any object in the scene.

There are a bunch of ways you can work around this, either have a custom component on the InputManager to receive the event and forward it to your MapController, or get a reference to the input action in code (either from the PlayerInput component, or from an InputActionReference set on the MapController).

Comment: Thanks for the response, that explains my confusion. I'm not going to have a class dedicated to tracking each action and routing it... That's the entire point of the input class in the first place and I don't want to have one tightly coupled class to work around failings in Unity's loosely coupled design... I might as well use the old input system in that case. I also don't intend to have every object in my game that  _might_ require input sit under a PlayerInput object... I have multiple top-level objects in the scene for difference concerns 1/

Comment: I'm also underwhelmed by the C# event implementation as it appears to be the least efficient design possible.... Invoke _all_ objects any time _any_ action is fired, so I suppose that leaves the inanely verbose Unity Events. I'm frankly staggered at how badly designed the new input system is. 2/2

Comment: Complaining on StackExchange is not the way to reach the developers who can act on that feedback.

Comment: using an InputActionReference and listening to action.performed is is probably what you want here.